# Batch convert video files for upload to Flickr

Tags: video, conversion, flickr

I have hundreds of home video files in various formats (AVI, MP4, MOV, etc) in sub-folders in a \My Photos folder on my Windows 7 PC. I would like to upload all of these to my Flickr account. But Flickr [supports](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/supported-video-file-formats-flickr-sln7693.html) only certain video formats.

What is the easiest way to convert all these files into a Flickr-friendly format? I know there are many [video converter tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_converters) out there but I am not sure what "preset" (i.e. output format, codec, frame rate, height/width, etc) to use to make it compatible with Flickr? Ultimately, the goal is to view the video on a mobile device (phone, tablet, Chromecast to TV, etc).

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I use ffmpeg.  Here is a site that should make it easy: 
http://andrebluehs.net/blog/converting-avi-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg/

responding to comment for gui:

I just googled "video to mp4 gui ffmpeg" and came up with WinFF.  I downloaded it and ran it.  It seems good.  This is what I would try.  Good luck.

Comment: ffmpeg has too many knobs to tweak. I am looking for a GUI that I can drag and drop 100s of files, select a Flickr preset that determines the optimal transcoding parameters for Flickr and click a button and come back in a few hours. Any other ideas?